# Perl regex where pattern is output from linux command

Tags: regex, perl

I have a linux command `statistics -o -u i1,1,1` which returns

```
max count[0]:=31
max count:=31
```

I would like to pluck out the number 31 in my perl script. I can do it from the command line using awk piped to head

`statistics -o -u i1,1,1 | awk -F':=' '{print $2}' | head -n1`

or similarly using grep

```
statistics -o -u i1,1,1 | grep -Po '(?<=max count:=)\d+'
```

or sed...

How can I do similar within a perl script?

---

EDIT 
Essentially, I would like to replace a backtick system call inside perl code with a pure perl solution.

Comment: Question is, if you have two working commands already, why would you need another? What are you trying to do?

Comment: are you going to pipe it, or reading from a named file?

Comment: @TLP I was thinking of using my $variable = `statistics -o -u i1,1,1 | grep -Po '(?<=max count:=)\d+'`. Is this acceptable in perl or preferable to use pure perl?

Comment: @MiguelPrz I will use this variable in a perl while loop

Comment: @moadeep Are you trying to replace a backtick system call inside perl code with a pure perl solution? If so, this was not a very good way to ask about it.

Comment: @TLP I am. Though I would still need to use backticks for the statistics call

Comment: @moadeep Yes, you would, but you can save a process.. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @moadeep What does your statistics command do?

Comment: @TLP it is custom software that picks up various statistics from medical images - max count, noise...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can emulate the awk:

```
perl -F":=" -lane 'print $F[1]'
```

Or you can emulate the grep:

```
perl -nle 'print /(?<=max count:=)(\d+)/'
```

They do not work in the same way, in that the first one will give output for any line that contains `:=` followed by something.

The `-n` switch allows for reading of stdin or files, `-l` handles newlines and `-F` sets the delimiter for autosplit `-a`.

**Update:**

According to your comment, it seems what you want is to replace a system call with pure perl code:

```
my $variable = `statistics -o -u i1,1,1 | grep -Po '(?<=max count:=)\d+'`;
```

The `statistics` command is unknown to me, so I do not know of a pure perl way to replace it, though something might exist on cpan. You can save yourself one process by processing the output in perl though. Something like this should work:

```
my @lines = grep /max count:=/, qx(statistics -o -u i1,1,1);
my ($num) = $lines[0] =~ /max count:=(\d+)/;
```

The `qx()` operator works exactly the same way as backticks, I just use it as a personal preference.

Comment: Actually I like to think of `\` cmd \`` as a shortcut for `qx\` cmd \``. ( Same with `'abc'` => `q'abc'`, and `"ab$c"` => `qq"ab$c"` )